# Line bundle of Half integral weight modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\omega_{X}$ denote the line bundle of cusp forms of weight $\frac{1}{2}$ over $X$, where $X=\Gamma\backslash \mathbb{H}$ and $\Gamma$ is any arbitrary fuchsian subgroup. Is it true that the line bundle of cusp forms of weight $k$, where $k\in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$ is $\omega_{X}^{2k}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tilde G$ be the universal covering group of $G=SL_2({\mathbb R})$ and let $\theta:{\mathbb R}\to SO(2)=K$ be the universal covering map with kernel $\mathbb Z$. 
Then ${\mathbb R}\cong\tilde K$, the universal covering of $K$, is a subgroup of $G$.
The bundle you are interested in correponds to the character of $\tilde K\cong\mathbb R$ with kernel $4\mathbb Z$.
The tensor powers of this bundle correspond to the tensor powers of the character, whence the claim follows.